# Disable bouncy scrolling in phonegap or "phonegap build" app for WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I wanted to disable the bouncing when scrolling outside the viewport area
is there any way to solve this problem in phonegap or "phonegap build" app for WP8

Comment: What bouncing do you mean?
Do you have some code?
Can you make a video or a detailed explanation of your discribed "bouncing"?

Comment: hi Sithys，thanks for your reply，let me explain again，step1，http://www.littlebau.com/1138.jpg，step2，http://www.littlebau.com/1139.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before when developing HTML5 apps for Windows Phone 8. To fix it, I added the following to your app's CSS file:

```
body {
    -ms-touch-action:none;
}
```

This will stop your page being able to move around and remove the bounce effect when you scroll to the edge.

Comment: hi james，your answer I had tried before，if use your way，although the "bouncing" affect is disappear，but the original "Vertical scrolling" affect disappear too

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, i've just seen your Screenshots!

You have to go into your config.xml and change the value

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
```

to

```
"true"
```

instead!

Comment: hi Sithys，have you really test this attribute in your PGB ? as far as I know，the "DisallowOverscroll" attribute only work in Android and iOS

Comment: look at this address，http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File，and search the keywords "DisallowOverscroll"

Comment: page says "Applies to Android and iOS."

Comment: Setting this property also messes up completely the scrolling process, which is delayed until the ontouchend event takes place.